# How can I create this ornament section?

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations, text-decorations, pgfornament

[image: Option 1]
or
[image: Option 1]

I would like to create a pattern for each section to display a line in the line of the question number, and below the right aligned, score of the question.

How can I create this ornament in \section??

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please show us a short, compilable code you have so far?

Comment: You can use `adforn` or `dingbat` packages (among others), which contain some fancy symbols for ornaments. You can find the entire catalogue of these and other symbols in [The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[display]{\normalsize\bfseries\sffamily}%
{ \raisebox{-1.25ex}{\parbox{2cm}{Question~\num[minimum-integer-digits = 2, detect-all]{\thesection}}}\color{Gainsboro}\titlerule[2pt]}{0em}{{ \vspace*{-2.1ex}
\hspace*{2cm}\color{Gainsboro}\titlerule[2pt]}\llap{\raisebox{-2ex}{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\section{2 points}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: error in xcolor Gainsboro!

ERROR: Option clash for package xcolor. \usepackage

Comment: I fixed this error:
\definecolor{Gainsboro}{rgb}{0.86, 0.86, 0.86}

Comment: @MarcioLord - The errors you say you're getting indicate that you didn't really take on board all of Bernard's code. (Aside: Bernard's code compiles just fine.) It's not helpful or informative to leave comments about errors which aren't actually caused by the code that was provided in an answer.

Comment: @MarcioLord: It most probably means another package already loads `xcolor` without option. In this case, simply declare  `svgnames` as an option of your `\documentclass`.

Comment: Thank you so much @Bernard